# jQplot OHLC Renderer mouseover for the bars

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I have just implemented a chart using **jQplot** plugin. I have used **OHLCRenderer** as the renderer and the chart looks like this.

[image: My jQplot OHLCRenderer chart with multiple stack]

Can you please tell me how to add a mouse-over option to the bars so that i can show some information when i mouse-over each bars. Thanks

This is the code

```
var catOHLC = [
    [1, 10, 6.5, 10, 10],
[2, 1.2, 5, 1.2, 1.2],
[3, 8, 10, 8, 8],
];

var catOHLC1 = [
    [1, 0, 5, 0, 0]

];

var ticks = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];
var ticks2 = [12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0];
plot4 = $.jqplot('chart4', [catOHLC, catOHLC1], {
    stackSeries: true,
  axes: {
      xaxis: {
          renderer:$.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
          ticks:ticks
      },
      yaxis: {
          tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
          ticks: ticks2,
          max: 24,
          min: 0
      }
  },
  series: [{ renderer: $.jqplot.OHLCRenderer, rendererOptions: { candleStick: false, tickLength: 0, lineWidth: 10 } },
  { renderer: $.jqplot.OHLCRenderer, rendererOptions: { candleStick: false, tickLength: 0, lineWidth: 10 } }],
});});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the jqplot highlighter plugin to make this work with a slightly modified version of your code. [Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9R3Mp/11/), and the code is below. Note that this is fairly similar to the example at http://www.jqplot.com/tests/candlestick-charts.php .

```
plot4 = $.jqplot('chart4', [catOHLC, catOHLC1], {

    series: [{
        renderer: $.jqplot.OHLCRenderer,
        rendererOptions: {
            tickLength: 4,
            lineWidth: 10
        }
    }, {
        renderer: $.jqplot.OHLCRenderer,
        rendererOptions: {
            tickLength: 4,
            lineWidth: 10
        }
    }],

    highlighter: {
        show: true,
        showMarker: false,
        tooltipAxes: 'xy',
        yvalues: 4,
        formatString: '<table class="jqplot-highlighter"> \
  <tr><td>x:</td><td>%s</td></tr> \
  <tr><td>open:</td><td>%s</td></tr> \
  <tr><td>hi:</td><td>%s</td></tr> \
  <tr><td>low:</td><td>%s</td></tr> \
  <tr><td>close:</td><td>%s</td></tr></table>'
    }
});
```

Comment: No. its not working. I have added the code in the question. Can you please check.

Comment: Rewrote the answer, please try now.

Comment: Good Work!! Thanks. This will help me a bit. But why in your jSfiddle its not showing the date,open,hi,low and close?

Comment: You need to use formatString if you want to customize the tooltip. The placeholder %s will be replaced with each y-value, one by one. I've updated the answer and the jsfiddle to do this so it's obvious.